# Jquery beforeunload event not firing in any browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

It's not firing when I close the browser. I have researched the issue a lot and found similar kinds of solution, but it is still not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
        return confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
    })
});
```

Comment: Probably because `bind` has been deprecated. Replace `bind` to `on`.

Comment: I tried on as well

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using below piece of code.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  return confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
});
```

If you want to perform some other things after user clicks yes, you can write that under

```
  $(window).on('unload', function(){
 //DoSomething
 });
```

Comment: write this event outside  $(document).ready(function())}; and then try

Comment: I think you re using  **jQuery version 3** or higher. It does not support **$(window)** inside **$(document)**. Write it outside and it should work

Answer (score 0):

I normally just use this:

```
(function($){
    $(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
        return true;
    })
})(jQuery);
```